# verilog debugging

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I don't know what is wrong with the code below. Can someone help me debug?

```
module iloop(z,a);
    input [31:0] a;
    output z;
    reg [4:0] i;
    reg s, z;
    initial begin
        s = 0;
        for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)  s = s | a[i];
        z = !s;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code has an infinite loop.  You have declared `i` as a 5-bit reg, which means its range of values is (decimal) 0 to 31.  But, your for loop checks if `i < 32`, which is always true.
Once i=31, `i` is incremented and rolls over to 0.

`$display` is your friend.  If you add it to your for loop, you will see the problem:

```
for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) begin $display(i); s = s | a[i]; end
```

I think you want `i<31`.

Or, maybe you want to OR all the bits of `a` together, using the bit-wise OR operator:

```
s = |a;
```

You should explain in words what you are trying to achieve.